# How to change the default window for new tabs in bash/shell scripts in KDE?

Tags: bash, shell, kde-plasma

I have a script, the relevant part of which I am showing below. What I would like to do is every few tabs start a new window. E.g., say I get to 20 tabs then I set LINUX_NEW_WINDOW=y and that opens a new window. So far so good however when I next clear LINUX_NEW_WINDOW such as LINUX_NEW_WINDOW='' then I would expect the next tab to go into the new window I just created but instead the next tab goes back to the first window I created. How do I get all new tabs to appear in the newly created 2nd window?

You will see $GREP in there and perhaps some other basic commands like expressed as a variable, please just read them as grep etc. It's because I have to port this code between my Linux box and my company's Apple laptop with is running homebrew... it handles some compatibility issues. You can also ignore APPLE_WINDOW_TYPE as this question is purely for Linux, I don't actually care if I solve this particular issue on the Apple box... basically, ignore any code that's for the Apple which will mostly be case statements to run code based on which OS we're on but for this question it's all Linux so you can safely ignore that code.

FILE: The one that calls spawn.sh in a loop. The loop has been stripped down for brevity but there should be enough there to get the idea. Also, I added the variable tabCount to show how a new window would be periodically opened (see the If...then...else...fi) however I just threw that in as an example for this question, it's NOT tested code so if there is minor error/typo please just read it for the "gist" of it.

```
CLOSE_TABS='n'
LINUX_NEW_WINDOW=''
APPLE_WINDOW_TYPE='window'

local spawnedCount=0
local tabCount=0
for site_raw in "${sites[@]}";
do

  # Launch the process that will process this site.
  . ./includes/spawn.sh "./batch/$TASK.sh" -s "$site_short" -t "$site_type" $launch_browser

  ((spawnedCount++))
  ((tabCount++))

  if [ $tabCount -ge 50 ]; then
    tabCount=0
    CLOSE_TABS='n'
    LINUX_NEW_WINDOW='y'
    APPLE_WINDOW_TYPE='tab'
  else
    CLOSE_TABS='y'
    LINUX_NEW_WINDOW=''
    APPLE_WINDOW_TYPE='tab'
  fi

  sleep 2

done
```

FILE: spawn.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1 # See if it eliminates the error we got that seemed to be due to timing.

TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES="$LOG_DIR/varsToTx.sh"
function save_vars_and_join_display() {
  join_display_root
  # The information to derive USER_GROUP & USER_USER gets lost when spawning
  # which we get from "who am i" in bash.
  set |$GREP -P '^(USER_(USER|GROUP)|PROJECT_NAME_QUERY)=' > "$TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES"
  chmod 775 "$TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES"
  chown $USER_USER:$USER_GROUP "$TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES" # Just to make it easier to delete if we want.
}

desktop=$(echo "$DESKTOP_SESSION" | $GREP -Po 'gnome|kde|plasma|xfce' | head -n1)
if [ -z "$desktop" ]; then
  desktop=$(echo "$WINDOWMANAGER" | $GREP -Po 'gnome|kde|plasma|xfce' | head -n1)
fi

if [ "$CLOSE_TABS" == 'y' ]; then
  noClose=''
else
  noClose='--noclose'
fi

case "$(uname -s)" in
    Linux*)
      case $desktop in
        gnome) 
          save_vars_and_join_display
          gnome-terminal -e "./includes/spawned.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9" & # Not yet tested
        ;;
        kde|plasma)
          save_vars_and_join_display
          # The '2>/dev/null' below gets rid of: 'QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread'
          if [ "$LINUX_NEW_WINDOW" == 'y' ]; then
            konsole $noClose -e "./includes/spawned.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9" 2>/dev/null &
          else
            konsole $noClose --new-tab -e "./includes/spawned.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9" 2>/dev/null &
          fi
        ;;
        xfce) echo 'Not implemented.' ;;
      esac
    ;;

    Darwin*)
      if [ "$APPLE_WINDOW_TYPE" == "window" ]; then
        osascript<<EOF
          tell application "Terminal"
            do script "cd \"`pwd`\"; echo; echo; $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"
          end tell
EOF
      elif [ "$APPLE_WINDOW_TYPE" == "tab" ]; then
        osascript<<EOF
          tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            delay 0.5
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
            repeat while contents of selected tab of window 1 starts with linefeed
              delay 0.01
            end repeat
            do script "cd \"`pwd`\"; echo; echo; $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9" in window 1
          end tell
EOF
        sleep 2
      fi
    ;;
#    CYGWIN*) ;;
#    MINGW*)  ;;
#    *)       ;;
esac
```

FILE: spawned.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES="logs/varsToTx.sh" # This we have to hard code since this is a spawned process and all variables have been lost.
if [ -e "$TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES" ]; then
  . "./$TX_FILE_FOR_BG_PROCESSES"
fi
. $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with code that doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sure, hopefully I did a little better than that, I've put the two complete files that do the spawning up and added a cut down version of the loop that would call them. I've also added some detail to my preamble to the code so some of the less obvious makes sense.

Comment: It is really unclear what you end goal is. I guess "tab" in new window is something I don't understand on plasma. In KDE3, the new tab in the konsole window is controlled with DCOP which was replaced by DBUS for KDE4/Plasma, e.g. [Plasma/DBusInterface](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/DBusInterface). If you want new tabs in a konsole window -- I'd follow that route (I have a little dcop script that restores 9 konsole tabs and makes 4 ssh sessions on startup). What new "tab" are you creating?, in what window?, and for what purpose? Is this an "Activities" tab?

Comment: Perhaps this will make it clear. When you open a terminal "window" you then have the option from the menu to select "New Tab" to create tabs in the terminal window. If you want a 2nd terminal window you select "New Window" from the terminal menu and you will have a 2nd Terminal window to work from and then you can add tabs with "New tab" in that 2nd window. We do this as humans all the time opening as many windows as we want and adding tabs to them. I'm just trying to do that programmatically but it keeps throwing new tabs back to the first window even after creating a 2nd window.